# Combine or Separate Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, schema, normalization

I'm confused on whether I should combine two tables or leave them separated. The ff is just one set of that problem of mine:

```
tblPhone(Phone_ID, Phone_Number, Phone_Type_ID, Person_ID)
tblPhone(Phone_Type_ID, Phone_Type_Name)
```

or

I should simply have it as:

```
tblPhone(Phone_ID, Phone_Number, Phone_Type_Name, Person_ID)
```

**Does one have advantage over the other?** Is there like a **standard guideline or practice** for table creation? For example, I remember someone telling me if a table isn't 3 or more, just combine it to another table, something like that...how true is that? I remember a little bit of normalization rules...but it can be very confusing at times. I think this falls on the third normalization rule that's why they should be separated, am I mistaken? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that this illustrates the third normal form.

You are normalizing the `Phone_Type_Name` out of `tblPhone` (we assume you mean to call the second `tblPhoneType`).  This is correct and a common practice. Even if you have just two columns in `tblPhoneType` now, eventually you may need to expand it to include other attributes related to phone types, and that is the easiest way to illustrate why you should normalize it.

#### Likely future scenario (need more columns):

By normalizing it now, you have protected yourself against this:

```
tblPhone(Phone_Type_ID, Phone_Type_Name, Phone_Type_Min_Price, Phone_Type_Max_Price)
```

Comment: That's quick and exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks! Oh, how about performance-wise? Let's say, for example, I'm 100% sure there would be no future scenario wherein I would have to add something in tblPhoneType...should I still separate it?

Comment: If it is normalized and you have properly defined a `FOREIGN KEY` constraint on `tblPhone` into `tblPhoneType`, then the key column in both tables will have enforced an index.  Performance should be equal to if you did not separate them and _did_ index the `Phone_Type_Name` column.  However, if you forgot to index it, performance could actually be worse than if you did the normalization.

Comment: Indexing...why weren't we taught of this. I just had a quick read...I just learned that index speeds up `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, I guess I could see that's very handy for `Phone_Type_Name`. Is that why you chose to suggest an index on `Phone_Type_Name`? Or is there something I'm not seeing? But I just read that indexing also slows down `INSERT` and `UPDATE`...I guess that just means I should separate `tblPhoneType` after all, as I would insert phone details in `tblPhone` very often. Right?

Comment: @Fred If you normalized it and defined the FOREIGN KEY, then you automatically get an index too.  But if you didn't normalize and you would need to use `Phone_Type_Name` to filter in your `WHERE`, or perform `GROUP BY` aggregates, you may need an index to achieve the best performance. There is a trade-off for inserts and updates, and you wouldn't usually index every column.

Comment: Ah, I see I see. I understand it better now. Thanks a lot, I learned a lot from this discussion.